# 73 F100 ignition

Tags: electrical, ford, wiring, f100

73 F100 Electronic distributor (no points)

**NEED CORRECT WIRING FOR/TO EACH OF THESE DEVICES **

Ign switch (Blk w/grn, Yellow, Red, Pink & two Red w/grn - on one terminal )

ICM (2 + 4 w/Blue square)

Starter Solenoid

Ballast (ceramic 2 terminal)

Coil (screw terminals)

Electronic Distributor

Wiring diagrams from net arent working.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You need *which* wiring going to each of these devices/connections? Are you wanting to know what to hook up to these out of the wiring harness? Or where they ultimately lead? Do you have a wiring harness in the truck already? You've really not given much to go on here, which makes this a very broad question.

Comment: **NEED CORRECT WIRING FOR/TO EACH OF THESE DEVICES ** means these are the devices in my particular circuit which I need to know the correct wiring connecting each of these devices together.  

(My ignition switch wires are stated and the devices I need connected together with this switch are also stated.

Thanks for responding.

Comment: What Engine?.., 5 options, 3.9L, 4.9L, 5.0l, 5.9L, 6.4L.

Comment: Its a 460, 7.5L ... but this shouldnt have anything to do with the 73 wiring for the ignition circuit.